# Cannot use internal memory partition in my Nextbook 7 16GB tab

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have just purchased a Nextbook 7 16 gb tab. I have installed only a few apps and then got the message of "Insufficient Memory". I looked in the storage section and found the tab has TWO partitions under "Internal Storage" One has space of 0.98GB and another internal storage has 12.22GB. All my apps are installed in the first partition. How to use the larger partition for apps? So far I have been unable to do so. KINDLY HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Every user of this tablet is having this issue. The company supposedly put out a firmware fix, but when you download the files to install it, they are corrupted. Which either means they are incompetent or purposely put out files that are corrupt so they can say "oh sorry" and never address the issue. Either way I'm not too optimistic.

http://nx700qc.blogspot.com/2014/11/trying-to-update-firmware.html?showComment=1417564996972#c1557705469401201898

http://www.nextbookusa.com/download.php